Toast сообщение в Android Studio
У меня есть автотест авторизации с не валидными данными который при клике на кнопку войти вызывает Toast сообщение, но проблема в том, что я уже и кастомный делать Toast и Decorwiev и ничего не помогает закончить тест успешной проверкой всплывающего Toast
Как это реализовать ?
@Rule
public ActivityScenarioRule<AppActivity> mActivityScenarioRule =
        new ActivityScenarioRule<>(AppActivity.class);

@Test
public void Authorization_with_no_valid_data() {
    onView(isRoot()).perform(waitDisplayed(R.id.login_text_input_layout, 7000));
    onView(withId(R.id.login_text_input_layout)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.login_edit_text)).perform(click(), typeText("log2"));
    onView(withId(R.id.password_text_input_layout)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.password_edit_text)).perform(click(), typeText("pass2"));
    closeSoftKeyboard();
    onView(withId(R.id.enter_button)).perform(click());

    onView(withText("Something went wrong. Try again later."))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}

